# In Adventurers League (season 8 rules), is a consumable magic item found during the adventure unlocked?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, dnd-adventurers-league

Suppose I play through an AL adventure wherein a *potion of flying* is found. I know that I or another character can keep that potion, using it during that adventure or saving it for a later adventure. But is the *potion of flying* unlocked for me to buy more with Treasure Checkpoints if I want? It is on Magic Item Table D, which means it would cost 16 TCP of tier 2 or higher.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## In Season 9, one player keeps the consumable

Season 9 of Adventurers League **did away with unlocks** for all types of magic items (as well as TCP). Regarding consumables, the ALDMG (v9.1, p. 4) now says:

> Consumable magic items (potions, scrolls, ammunition, and soul coins) are **equitably divided** among the characters - resolving disagreements randomly if necessary.

---

*The question still refers to Season 8 specifically, so I'm keeping this section for posterity, even though Season 8 rules are no longer in effect.*

## In Season 8, all characters unlocked the consumable

The official document [Detect Thoughts](http://dndadventurersleague.org/detect-thoughts-volume-1-3/) (version 1.3, page 2, emphasis mine) says:

> ### Regarding Magic Items
>
> When a consumable magic item (that is a potion, scroll, or parcel of magical ammunition, only) is found by the characters, the intent is that a consumable item may be immediately kept by one character and **is subsequently unlocked for everyone present** (including the character that got to keep it).

According to Community Manager Amy Lynn Dzura in the same link,

> The information that we round up [in Detect Thoughts] will find its way into the appropriate documents when the next revision of our documentation comes around.

Unfortunately, the AL Dungeon Master's Guide (version 8.2) currently implies that you *don't* unlock the item, so you'll want to keep a copy of Detect Thoughts handy until they update the AL DMG.